# UIView Overlapping

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have `UIView` that have some subview of the same custom `UIView`.
after i add them to the Main `UIView` i add it to an array too, and when i finish to add them i want to check if some of the `UIViews` have Overlapping, so i check it with the :

```
bool CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2)
```

My issue is that i want to know what is the `CGRect` of the Overlapping, because i want to paint it with another background color, there is any ready method for detecing it?

Comment: So you are trying to find an area - let's call it rect3 - that equals the area shared by rect1 & rect2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CGRect rect3 = CGRectIntersection (
   CGRect rect1,
   CGRect rect2
);
```

rect3 is the overlapping area, shared by both rect1 and rect2.

Comment: and the CGRect that i get is the area in the mainview?

Comment: From the documentation: "A rectangle that represents the intersection of the two specified rectangles. If the two rectangles do not intersect, returns the null rectangle. To check for this condition, use CGRectIsNull."